# linum not working on startup with viper mode (emacs)

Tags: emacs, elisp, viper-mode

My `.emacs` file:

```
;; viper mode default
(setq viper-mode t)
(require 'viper)

;; add to load path
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elisp/")

;; line number
(require 'linum)
(global-linum-mode 1)
(setq linum-format "%4d \u2502 ") ;; add spacing between numbering and text
```

When I comment out `viper` settings, line numbers show up as soon as I open up a file. When I enable `viper` on startup, line numbers do not show, I must do `M-x linum-mode` manually.

Comment: Maybe a silly suggestion, but did you try to switch them around?

Comment: Could've sworn I tried that and it didn't work, but I tried it again and that seems to have fixed it - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a silly suggestion, but did you try to switch them around?